# Autodesk Maya per pixel surface position and normals through whole scene

Tags: position, shader, maya, surface, normals

how can I get in maya per pixel all surface positions and normals of the entire scene.

I don't want to stop at the first viewed surface of the camera. I need to get information about all object. I want to traverse the whole scene

For example a cube is in front of the sphere. The camera position just shows the cube - the sphere gets at that camera position by the cube. My output of every pixel position of my camera rendered image data gives me information of the surface position in world space and the normal of the cube at the first hit. Then again for the other side of the cube. Then the two surfaces of the sphere.

How can that be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Which renderer do you want to use? Arnold, Viewport2...

Comment: The one which is the most suitable for the goal. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: The problem is that you need multiple datasets per pixel what is a bit tricky. You should have a look at deep image rendering with Arnold.